# Locally compact rings with reciprocals

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ac.commutative-algebra, fields

A topological field is defined to be a topological ring $F$ with reciprocals such that the reciprocal function $F\setminus\{0\} \to F\setminus\{0\}$ is continuous. Locally compact topological fields are well behaved and well understood [1].

What is known about locally compact topological rings with reciprocals for which reciprocation need not be continuous?

[1] [http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/8410Chapter5.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/8410Chapter5.pdf)

Comment: For a group with a locally compact topology with continuous multiplication the  inverse must be continuous by a theorem of Ellis https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1957-008-02/S0002-9939-1957-0083681-9/S0002-9939-1957-0083681-9.pdf

Comment: He later showed you don’t even need multiplication to be jointly continuous. It can be separately cts in each variable.

Comment: So to make it clear the reciprocal map must be continuous

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Thank you very much for the reference!